# Micro:Bit audio output - is it possible this way?

Tags: micropython

I wanted to get a little practice by working on some kind of project using Python (MicroPython in this case).

Some of you probably heard about Micro:Bit and what can it be used for, so I have a question: Let's say that I somehow connected speaker and I wanna play some song.
Is it possible to use Micro:Bit and store "songs" and play them in certain situation (for example if button A is pressed ?) using MicroPython ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
import microbit 
import music
music.play(['c4:4', 'a' ],microbit.pin0)
```

See the documentation at https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/music.html

And https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/music.html

Comment: Note there are a few known bugs with music (PWM). But if your program is simple the microbit won't exhibit them.  I believe they will be fixed and part of mu editor and command `uflash` within 2 months

Comment: I think that we didn't understand each other clearly. Those are notes, let's say that I record myself singing and want to play it on a speaker. Is that possible ?

Comment: I don't believe you can sample a microphone fast enough in micropython.  I think in C/C++ you may be able to. There's no point trying blocks it puts sleeps into loops to allow for scheduling of blocks like `on button_a is_pressed`

Comment: So you tell me if I use C/C++ I can download a song onto Micro:Bit and play it ? Song like Gangnam Style ? With guy fully singing etc...

Comment: You may be able to. There's a lot of caveats. Microbit has only 16kb of ram. So your music player and codec need to be small. Your program and mp3 file may be too big to fit on flash i think its only 256kb.  I don't think the underlying platform will support what you want to do.